# What is a Descendant operator? Is it in javascript Or in any other language?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

I came across a question stating:
**Which on of the following is a Descendant operator:**
A) ..
B) ... 
C) & 
D) *

*WHICH IS IT? AND PLEASE EXPLAIN WHY OR REFER ANY ARTICLE OR LINK*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is A.

The `..` operator is the descendant operator; you can use it in place of the normal . member-access operator :

```
var names = pt..name;
```

Comment: `..` is deprecated i guess.

Comment: Your code results in a SyntaxError. I don't think it's correct.

Comment: wot about ```...``` .. PS: i know it's spread operator but the site where i saw this question stated this is the right answer